# Filter Listview using Spinner

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, filter, spinner

I have a class that contains list view and spinner. List view contains multiple text items. I want to filter this list view by selecting the spinner item that contains one item in list view. I tried this but I have getting only one item in list view when selecting the spinner item. My coding given below.

**Expense class**

```
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private AndroidSQLiteData sdbData;

Spinner spinCat;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private NewDatabaseHandler ndbHandler;
ArrayAdapter<String> sAdaptr;

String catString;
String[] data;
List<String> sData;

public String theCategory="";

AllDataClass allData;
ListView exList;
private ArrayList<String> kId = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> t_category = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> t_date = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> t_amount=new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> t_moneytype=new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> t_description=new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.expense_tab_list);
    exList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listEx);

    spinCat=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerCategories);

    sdbData=new AndroidSQLiteData(this);
    sdbData.open();

    ndbHandler=new NewDatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    ndbHandler.open();

}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    displayData(theCategory);
    super.onResume();
}

private void displayData(final String theCategory)
{

    db=sdbData.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
            +AndroidSQLiteData.TABLE_NAME, null);


    kId.clear();
    t_category.clear();
    t_amount.clear();
    t_moneytype.clear();
    t_date.clear();
    t_description.clear();

    if(mCursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            kId.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(AndroidSQLiteData.KEY_ID)));
            t_category.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(AndroidSQLiteData.KEY_CATEGORY)));
            t_date.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(AndroidSQLiteData.KEY_DATE)));
            t_amount.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(AndroidSQLiteData.KEY_AMOUNT)));
            t_moneytype.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(AndroidSQLiteData.KEY_MONEY)));
            t_description.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(AndroidSQLiteData.KEY_DESCRIPTION)));

            catString= mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(AndroidSQLiteData.KEY_CATEGORY));

            if ( catString.length() > 0 && ! catString.equals(theCategory) )
                  continue;

        }

        while(mCursor.moveToNext());
    }


    allData=new AllDataClass(ExpenseTabList.this,kId, t_category, t_date, t_moneytype, t_amount, t_description);

    exList.setAdapter(allData);
    exList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


        data = ndbHandler.getAllLabels();


        for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++)
        {
            Log.i(this.toString(), data[i]);
        }

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner

        spinCat.setAdapter(adapter);


        spinCat.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {


            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long arg3) 
            {

                ExpenseTabList.this.theCategory =spinCat.getSelectedItem().toString();

                displayData(theCategory);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });


    mCursor.close();
}


}
```

**SQLite Database Class**

```
public class AndroidSQLiteData extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "expensedata";


public static final String TABLE_NAME = "expense";

// Labels Table Columns names
public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_CATEGORY = "category";
public static final String KEY_MONEY="moneytype";
public static final String KEY_DATE="date";
public static final String KEY_AMOUNT="amount";
public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION="description";


private SQLiteDatabase db=null;

public AndroidSQLiteData(Context context)
{
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sdb) 
{
    String CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_CATEGORY + " TEXT,"+KEY_DATE+ " TEXT," +KEY_MONEY+" TEXT," +KEY_AMOUNT+ " TEXT," +KEY_DESCRIPTION+ " TEXT)";
    sdb.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);       

}

public void insertData(String category, String date, String amount, String moneytype, String description)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_CATEGORY, category);
    values.put(KEY_DATE, date);
    values.put(KEY_MONEY, moneytype);
    values.put(KEY_AMOUNT, amount); 
    values.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, description);

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    db.close();


}

public List<String> getAllData(){
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())

    {
        do 
        {               
            data.add(cursor.getString(1));
        }

        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return data;
}

public void open()
{
    if(this.db==null)
    {
        this.db=this.getWritableDatabase();


    }

}

}
```

**Holder Class**

```
public class AllDataClass extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable
{

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<String> id;
private ArrayList<String> icategory;
private ArrayList<String> idate;
private ArrayList<String> iamount;
private ArrayList<String> imoneytype;
private ArrayList<String> idescription;

private View view;

public AllDataClass(Context mc,ArrayList<String> Id,ArrayList<String> icat,ArrayList<String> ida,ArrayList<String> iamt,
        ArrayList<String> imoney, ArrayList<String> ides)
{
    this.mContext=mc;
    this.id=Id;
    this.icategory=icat;
    this.idate=ida;
    this.iamount=iamt;
    this.imoneytype=imoney;
    this.idescription=ides;

}

@Override
public int getCount() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return id.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@Override
public View getView(int pos, View child, ViewGroup parent)
{
    view=child;
    Holder holder;

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    if (view == null) 
    {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.expense_list_item, null);
        holder = new Holder();
        holder.txtCat=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textCat);
        holder.txtDate=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
        holder.txtMoneyTyp=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textType);
        holder.txtDesc=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textDesc);
        holder.txtAmount=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textAmt);
        view.setTag(holder);

    }

    else
    {
        holder=(Holder)view.getTag();

    }


    holder.txtDate.setText("Date: "+idate.get(pos));
    holder.txtMoneyTyp.setText(iamount.get(pos));
    holder.txtCat.setText(icategory.get(pos));
    holder.txtDesc.setText(idescription.get(pos));
    holder.txtAmount.setText("Rs. "+imoneytype.get(pos));
    holder.txtAmount.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);


    return view;
}

public class Holder
{
    TextView txtCat;
    TextView txtDate;
    TextView txtMoneyTyp;
    TextView txtAmount;
    TextView txtDesc;
    TextView txtid;

}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() 
{

    return null;
}

}
```

How can I get filter whole list items with one item in spinner.. Please help..

Comment: `List view contains multiple text items.` ? Did you mean to say "The items in the listview contain multiple textviews"?   `want to filter this list view by selecting the spinner item that contains one item in list view.` ?? The spinner gives you a text. Or a search string. Now how do you want to filter? In which textview do you want to search that text? As getFilter() returns null doesn't a change of the spinner cause a NullPointerException?

Comment: Spinner gives t_category text. I want to filter by searching the t_category text in the list view and need to display this text and others in list.

Comment: Please answer my last question too. Why are you saying `and need to display this text and others in list` ? As they will be in the listview already before you start filtering.

Comment: You have two adapters. Why? Trow away sAdaptr.

Comment: There are some categories in Spinner that is Travel, Food etc. When selected Travel the list view should display like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/kFCyM.jpg     this is the way I am looking for..

Comment: And how does it display normally without filtering? And how if you choose another category? Show more pictures please. I start to believe that you do not want to filter the list of the adapter to a smaller one giving the listview less items. But instead just want to display the items differently. Please elaborate.

Comment: On the picture the listview has only one item with Travel.

Comment: please check this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/5KqUU.png   I want to filter like this. There will be different categories, Food, Shopping etc with Travel. Category in spinner and list view are same.

Comment: At start of your activity/fragment is there already a category choosen? Or are all categories displayed in the listview? For the latter i already asked confirmation and a picture too.

Comment: @greenapps  I have edited my question with your code. After doing this this is my output  http://i.stack.imgur.com/ImQnN.jpg  can not select the item from spinner. You can see an item in list shopping. If I selected shopping it should filter all shopping items in list. But I can not select shopping after this code. Please check the edited code..

Comment: You cannot select shopping? Well dont believe you. See my other remarks.

Answer (score 0):

I look out your code. I will give you an idea. Hope it will help you.

On spinner item click:

```
sp.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, View view, int position,
                    long longPosition) {

                    yourAdapter.updateList(filteredList);
            }
        })
```

filteredList is List or whatever your data.

and finally add updateList function in your adapter.

```
public void updateList (ArrayList<Object> filteredList) {
        this.filteredList= filteredList;

        //and call notifyDataSetChanged
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Hope it will help you.!!!

Comment: I can't create updateList(). Can you please explain with my code?

Comment: Can you please explain why you cannot create such a list? You have already your all data which contains six arraylist. Just loop through icategory searching for the wanted text. Then keep in list or remove. If you delete then delete items in the other lists with the same position.

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want with only minor changes. Change

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
displayData();
super.onResume();
}
```

to

```
String theCategory = "Travel"; // if you want to start with just Travel
String theCategory = "";  // if you want to start with all categories

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
displayData(theCategory);
super.onResume();
}
```

So you have to add that parameter to `displayData()`'.
Then in the `do` block first check the category and only add to the list if condition met.

Add as first statements:

```
String category = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(AndroidSQLiteData.KEY_CATEGORY));
if ( category.length > 0 && ! category.equals(theCategory) )
  continue;
```

In the spinner event handler you only need following code:

```
theCategory =spinCat.getSelectedItem().toString();

displayData(theCategory);
```

Comment: after doing this nothing happening in my app. I can not select an item from spinner. There is no error in logcat.

Comment: You should tell better what happens or not happens. It would be strange that you suddenly cannot select an item in a spiner. Something different would be that you can select what you want but nothing happens. You also did not tell which influence the default `theCategory` has in onResume. Please do tell!  If you don't tell more we cannot help you. I suggest you post your modified code in an extra codeblock here.

Comment: Yes you added the 'continue' code in the `do` block. But you added it as last lines so it has no effect at all. It does nothing there. Rethink! I had asked to add those lines as first lines in the `do` block. Please do. Further `String category` was a local variable. Why did you make it nearly global? Makes bad code!